# Sourcetree not detecting changes to a .dll file

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a .dll file that is tracked and added to source control (so it's not being ignored anywhere).
The problem is that I recently updated it but Sourcetree is not detecting that it changed.

Comment: Why are you adding binary DLL files to your Git repo?  In general, by-products of your build process should be getting versioned in Git.

Comment: It's a third-party dll that sometimes gets updated and I don't want to have to download it from them all the time and sometimes I just want to stay on a certain version.

Comment: Fair enough.  Are you certain that you updated this DLL on the branch in question?  What does `git status` show you from the bash?

Comment: Git status doesn't show that particular file. In my repo, I still have the same old file from a few months ago. I also tried git add but it seems like it's already added (no message or anything comes up)

Comment: Something is not right here.  If you update a file, _any_ file, Git should be able to detect that.

Comment: Are you sure the third party actually changed it?

Comment: @Horba Yes, when I decompile it, they have a different MVID and the main class is now internal instead of public (it being public caused problems with my own project on another machine which is how I noticed that Sourcetree hadn't updated this file.)

Comment: Does `git log whatever.dll` show that git knows about the file? (`git log -n 1` if you don't want a lot of output.) Do you have something like `*.dll` in your `.gitignore` (either at the root of the repo or in your home directory)?

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, when I use git log it shows the last time (and the only time) this file was commited which was back in June. I don't have any *.dll in any of my git ignores

Comment: have you just tried cloning the project to a diff directory and then applying your dll updates and see if sourcetree then picks it up? something may have just gone wrong in your local repo.

Answer (score 4):

- Try adding it again using
  `git add -f`
  One reason is "*.dll" might be in your global ignore.
  We can use `git check-ignore` to find out where the global gitignore file is.
- We can use the below command to check the files which are ignored by the gitignore:
  `git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others`

Comment: He stated that the file is tracked and added to source control. In this case, `.gitignore` no longer applies.

Comment: I doubt, if the changes were ignored temporarily to this file. May be running the  below command might help :                                                                                             
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

Comment: I've ran all of those and they always return nothing.

Comment: git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others lists all the correct files that are ignored (my file is not listed)

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Can you try, for testing, to update it again, and check with Git 2.19.1 in command line what git status return?

Comment: @VonC I get same as before: On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler you say you have that issue for a few other dlls: would that persists if you add them (and modify them) in a *new* Git repo?

Comment: @VonC Sorry for the delay. I just tried it and everything works fine if I commit them to a new Git repo. SourceTree gives a warning "No changes detected or this is a binary file" but it still allows me to stage it and commit it.

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler OK, strange. Maybe a difference in local configuration between the two repos.

Answer (score 0):

First, switch to command-line, using the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), in a CMD session with a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826648/6309).

There, go to your repo root folder, and type, using [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) :

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/your/file.dll
```

If that returns nothing, you are sure it is not ignored, and should be tracked.

Type, using [`git check-attr`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr):

```
git check-attr --all -- path/to/your/file.dll
```

If that returns nothing, that means no `.gitattributes` directive would be influencing the diff which should be detected.

Make sure `git status` mentions that you are on a branch (instead of a detached HEAD)

---

Update Feb. 2019 for Git 2.21: Asking "git check-attr" about a macro (e.g. "binary") on a specific path did not work correctly, even though "`git check-attr -a`" listed such a macro correctly.  This has been corrected.

See [commit 7b95849](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b95849be42406b2e23bcdc4592d71d8724361ba) (18 Jan 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 02bf766](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02bf766cc5d7580ce17dfab36fce976bfd06585b), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

That means, with Git 2.21, `git check-attr binary file` should return `file: binary: set`. (instead of `file: binary: unspecified`)

Comment: If the file is already tracked, `.gitignored` is no longer relevant.

Comment: Did both of those and nothing was returned. Git status says I'm on the master branch.

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler OK: what OS are you using? What version of Git?

Comment: @VonC git version 2.10.2.windows.1 on Windows 10 & SourceTree 2.5.5.0

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Can you check with Git 2.19.1 and Sourcetree set to Git system (not Git embedded)?

Comment: @VonC just tried but still the same. It's just not detecting changes to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Look into nuget to get the 3rd-party dll out of git.
Does the 3rd-party vendor provide a nuget feed for this assembly?

If not, It's worth asking them to start. If not, you can make one
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Do you already have private nuget feeds? If not it's worth looking into.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview

You're going to be so much happier getting the derived artifacts out of source.

Comment: No they don't and I don't care enough to make one. Also I'm having this issue for a few dll files, not just this one.

Comment: If you're having this issue for other files too, it sounds like you should care. It's pretty quick to setup.

Comment: None of the 3rd parties provide nuget feeds so I can't go aroud messaging them all hoping they will. Also the project is a Unity project which doesn't support nuget.